# How to force number 1 on title page?

Tags: page-numbering

```
\documentclass[titlepage, osajnl,twocolumn, showkeys,10pt]{revtex4-1}  
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\title{Some title}

\author{}
\email{}
\affiliation{}



\begin{abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}
%\onecolumngrid
\today
Student number: 
BSc Biochemistry
Abstract Word Count: 184
Word Count: 1476
%\twocolumngrid
\end{center}

\vspace*{50px}
 Some abstract 
\vspace*{25px}

\clearpage
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I already tried with `\thispagestyle{plain}` but no luck so far. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yor MWE is missing a `\documentclass` and so does not compile. With the `article` class you geta page number of the title page because of the `\thispagestyle{plain}`, so either you missed it when you checked or your documentclass is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat: `revtex4-1` is a class for electronic submissions to journals of the American Physical Society. So the settings are for that journals and you should not change them. I.e., the title page uses a special page style for title pages of those journals. You should not change it!*

However, if you want to ignore this, you can replace page style `titlepage`, e.g., by page style `plain`:

```
\documentclass[titlepage, osajnl,twocolumn, showkeys,10pt]{revtex4-1}  
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@titlepage\ps@plain
\makeatother

\title{Some title}

\author{}
\email{}
\affiliation{}



\begin{abstract}
%\thispagestyle{plain}% not needed
\begin{center}
%\onecolumngrid
\today
Student number: 
BSc Biochemistry
Abstract Word Count: 184
Word Count: 1476
%\twocolumngrid
\end{center}

\vspace*{50px}
 Some abstract 
\vspace*{25px}

\clearpage
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\end{document}
```